# Button disabled but the div inside is still calling function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to disable a button after it is clicked. I don't want to use pointer-events:none; as this can be disabled from the front-end under inspect. It needs to be disabled without possible manipulation from Inspect. How can I achieve this? setting disabled attribute still allows manipulation as they can just remove the attribute from inspect too. The entire div needs to be non-clickable.

```
<button key={tile} className={`${styles.tile} ${styles.button}`} onClick={goldClicked}>
                <div className={`${styles.cover}`}>
                  <img src={require("../../../assets/img/goldbar.png")} id={`button-${tile}`} className={`${styles.bomb} ${styles.displayOff}`} alt={`button-${tile}`}></img>
                </div>
              </button>
```

```
const goldClicked = (event) => {
        event.target.classList.add(`${styles.disableClick}`) // Currently disableClick is using pointer-events:none;
        event.target.setAttribute('disabled','') // disabling it by using attribute.
    
  }
```

I tried using pointers-events:none and setAttribute('disabled',''). They are both not feasible as they can be removed from Inspect. It needs to be non-clickable without possible manipulation from Inspect.

Comment: Just an idea, but would it be possible for you to create a state on true, and once you click the button you set it to false. And in your JSX, you render the button with the function when true, and when false render a button without any event ?

Comment: it's an impossible expectation. You have no control over the client rendering the page so it will always be possible to manipulate the page behaviour client side

Comment: Why does it matter if it can manipulated client side? The server should decide if an action is valid or not. And like Diego said, it's not possible to prevent the client from doing what it wants with the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to disable the button entirely, even for users who can manipulate the DOM using inspect, why not instead track when the button has already been clicked so you can control whether clicking it has an effect or not.

You can store some state to track whether or not the button has already been clicked:

```
const [wasClicked, setWasClicked] = useState(false);
```

You can then use the state to choose whether the button should be disabled or not.

```
<button key={tile} className={`${styles.tile} ${styles.button}`} onClick={goldClicked} disabled={wasClicked}>
    <div className={`${styles.cover}`}>
        <img src={require("../../../assets/img/goldbar.png")} id={`button-${tile}`} className={`${styles.bomb} ${styles.displayOff}`} alt={`button-${tile}`} />
    </div>
</button>
```

In your onClick handler, if the state is true, you can do nothing, or do something else.

```
const goldClicked = (event) => {
    if (wasClicked) {
        // the button has already been clicked, so do something here or do nothing
    } else {
        event.target.classList.add(`${styles.disableClick}`) // Currently disableClick is using pointer-events:none;
        event.target.setAttribute('disabled','') // disabling it by using attribute.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was useful. I did a similar workaround and now the button's disabled from the front and cannot be enabled back from client-side.